# Less files not being integrated by Meteor

Tags: meteor, less

Purchased a theme for my new app, which is entirely based on LESS. However, Meteor is not recognizing the @varable variables in the LESS files. I have over 100+ such files and these error lines span for that long as well.

[image]

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here by assuming Meteor will compile all the files because the layout isn't working correctly and these LESS file problems are the reason. Anything I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the version of less used in your purchased theme is compatible with the version of Meteor that your app is using. I had a similar issue recently where my purchased theme used an older version of less which was not compatible with Meteor 1.2. So, when I updated my app to the latest version of Meteor, my app layout was messed up as the less files were not properly interpreted. Please see [Breaking changes in Meteor 1.2](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Breaking-changes-in-Meteor-1.2#build-tool-and-package-improvements) - point 3 under *Build tool and package improvements*

Just my $0.02

Comment: Aw fuk bye. That's not good. Did you get the issue sorted out or a refund at least?

Comment: My theme came with Meteor 1.1.0.3. When the update to 1.2.1 messed up the layout, I reverted to the previous version due to lack of time. I am waiting for the theme provider to update their theme as I really liked it.